# If height of the browser screen (h) is less than (w/2)

Tags: css, media-queries

How can I set a rule for this?

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1)
```

Was my attempt but it doesn’t work properly.

I also tried

```
@media (min-height: 50vw)
```

No idea here. I don’t wanna use JavaScript. I want to create a scrollbar when the browser screen is less than the w/2.

Comment: Can't help you with your problem if you don't show your markup and explain what doesn't work. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but perhaps something like this could help:

```css
min-height: calc(100vw / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `min-aspect-ratio`. Perhaps some other issue in your code is preventing this property from functioning.

Here is an example, extracted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio

```css
/* Exact aspect ratio */
@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  div {
    color: red;
  }
}

/* Minimum aspect ratio */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
  div {
    background: yellow;
  }
}

/* Maximum aspect ratio */
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
  div {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio -->

<div>Watch this element as you resize your viewport's width and height.</div>
```